# convert from invalid to valid json

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have json which contains illegal characters

```
{"message":"A"B",
  "fromWhom":"53"}
```

I want plaint text which is sent from the sever spring to client, so that client can get the complete data.

How can I replace illegal characters of a string to a valid json object?

Comment: @davidhxxx flag as such, leaving a comment is not notifying any of the moderators.

Comment: @kryger ok, I will read the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is valid:

```
{
"message": "A B",
"fromWhom": "53"
}
```

Is there a reason you have a floating quote mark in there?

Also, this resource is useful for validating JSON.

http://jsonlint.com/

I hope this is the answer to your question.

EDIT:

If you must use the double quote, then you can escape it as shown below and it will be valid.

```
{
"message": "A\"B",
"fromWhom": "53"
}
```

Comment: I want to use double quote, data will be A"B, but I cannot use this character, that's my problem.

Comment: but how can I change this value, if it is a string in javascript?

Comment: When you use the backslash then only the quote will appear. So your string should look like A"B.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the quote.

```
    {
    "message": "A\"B",
    "fromWhom": "53"
    }
```

As for changing the value. I think you need to JSON.parse.

Example:

```
<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
obj.employees[1].lastName = "Timmy" //Value change here
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
</script>
```

Comment: but how can I change this value, if it is a string in javascript?

Comment: If this is what your finding please accept this as your answer :D