# Encoding JSON data to preserve the json format

Tags: javascript, c#, json

As JSON values are generated dynamically and the values in it are based on user inputs, So if user inputs an unacceptable character like `"` in a string it will make the json invalid.

something like:

```
{
     "tag" : "demo",
     "value": "user " input" 
}
```

Is there a way to encode or escape the JSON values?

Comment: Um, you use a JSON API. *Don't* try to build up the JSON as a string manually, any more than you would do so for XML. Now, are you actually asking in Javascript or in C#? I can give an example in C#, but I'd find it harder to do in Javascript.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using it both in C# and javascript. Could you please recommand some APIs?

Comment: Well in C# I'd use Json.NET if I were you. I don't know what the appropriate recommendation would be in Javascript, but I'm sure a bit of research will find you lots of options.

Comment: In JavaScript `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Funny, there was [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38420652/6303733) an hour ago in Java doing the same thing (closed as duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19176024/6303733)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon Skeet and gcampbell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JSON.stringify` for this. It will add escape character `\` automatically.

Following is a sample:

```js
function processValues(){
  var v1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var v2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
  var o = {
    value1: v1,
    value2: v2
  };
  var result = JSON.stringify(o);
  console.log(result);
}

function test1(){
  document.getElementById("txt1").value = "Hello";
  document.getElementById("txt2").value = 'World! "test"';
}

test1();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
<input type="text" id="txt2"/>
<button onclick="processValues()">Create JSON string</button>
```

Comment: Rajesh thanks for your answer. What should I do for the json generated on server side via c#

Comment: If you are sending an object, then no issues. If you are sending string, then you will have to use `JSON.parse`. Note: if you are using MVC 4+, you can look into WebApi, which are data driven controllers. If not, there are many libraries that can help you convert Lists into JSON object